# Removing a line from XML file using xmllint in shell script

Tags: xml, bash, shell, xmllint

I have a xml file in a particular directory now I want to remove a particular entry (see example) from the file and update the existing xml file using shell script.

Example: (See code) I have to remove line 4 (entry of a particular resource)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest:manifest xmlns:manifest="....." manifest:version="1.2">
 <manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="/" manifest:version="1.2" manifest:media-type="..."/>
"line to be deleted" <manifest:file-entry manifest:full-path="...." manifest:media-type="..."/>
 ......some more lines....
 </manifest:manifest>
```

Help will be appreciated :)
I am new at this and not much aware about editing a xml file, from some sources I have found that xmllint can be used but I am not sure about that.

Comment: It's good that you don't want to do this with line-based tools like `grep` or `sed`, since XML is not flat, but the question doesn't make it clear what exactly you want to remove (other than that it is a `manifest:file-entry` tag). What are the criteria?

Comment: I have to remove a particular file from a zip package to save the space. Since I have deleted the file directly from the shell script, now I want to remove the file entry from the manifest file to ensure proper functioning.

Comment: @Beginner I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. So, did you use my advice or something else? And what exactly happened?

Comment: I have used grep or xmlstarlet it worked for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, `xmllint` is not made for editing XML files, so you can't do that.

---

One possible solution to your problem is command:

`grep -v your_pattern your_file > new_file`

It will choose all other lines than the one and copy it into a new file.

---

Another, probably the better way, is using of `xmlstarlet` ([documentation](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch04s03.html)).

You can use it like this:

```bash
xmlstarlet ed --delete your_xpath input.xml > output.xml
```

Comment: If you're content with this answer, you can accept it to make this question marked as "solved" :-)

Comment: I upvoted the solution using **xmlscarlet**, not the one using **grep**